# How to write test spec for an Angularjs service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-service

I have little Angular Service to store and retrieve data. How do I write Jasmine test spec for testing this service?

```
angular.module("myServices").factory('dataStore', [
    function() {
      var DATASTORE;
      DATASTORE = {};
      return {
        get: function(id) {
          if (DATASTORE[id] != null) {
            return DATASTORE[id];
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        },
        put: function(id, data) {
          return DATASTORE[id] = data;
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

The below spec doesn't working for me:

```
"use strict";
describe("Service: dataStore", function() {
  var store;
  store = null;
  beforeEach(function() {
    module("myServices").inject([
      'dataStore', function(dataStore) {
        return store = dataStore;
      }
    ]);
  });
  it("should return null", function() {
    expect(store.get('some')).toBe(null);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should load your module within a `beforEach` block. After that you may use the `inject` function - angular and jasmin will do the rest for you.

```
"use strict";
describe("Service: dataStore", function() {
  var store;

  beforeEach(module('myServices'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(dataStore){
      store = dataStore;
  }));

  it("should return null", function() {
    expect(store.get('some')).toBe(null);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading this [Testing Angular Services Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.testing_services) should get you started

As for your problem, inject the `myServices` module in the *beforeEach* block and the `dataStore` service in the *it* block.

```
beforeEach(module('myServices'));

it("should return null", 
  inject(function(dataStore) {
    expect(dataStore.get('some')).toBe(null);  
}));
```